# Can't Receive data from Arduino to MIT inventor app

Tags: arduino

I'm working on an IOT project for school, but I'm having trouble seeing my data from the Arduino using Bluetooth module to my MIT apps. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
char Incoming_value = 0;
                
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);         
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);       
}

void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available() > 0)  
  {
    Incoming_value = Serial.read();      
    Serial.print(Incoming_value);        
    Serial.print("\n");        
    if(Incoming_value == '1'){
      digitalWrite(12, HIGH); 
      delay(10000);
      Serial.println("5");
    }
               
  }                            
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOKtM.png)

fixing for receiving data from Arduino using Bluetooth module

Comment: the arduino will only send data if it received data first. And your MIT app doesn't seem to be sending any data to the arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if you are connecting a Bluetooth module to the arduino board,use SoftwareSerial.
here is a working example : 

//----------------------------------------------------------------    

    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    SoftwareSerial btm(3, 2); // pin D3 and pin D2 as Rx and Tx
    
    char c;
    
    void setup() {
      btm.begin(9600);
      Serial.begin(9600);
    }
    
    void loop() {
      if (btm.available() > 0) {
            while (btm.available() > 0) {
              c = btm.read();
              Serial.print(c);
        }
      }
    }

//----------------------------------------------------------------
```